# why does SQLite complain that _id column not found when it's included

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, simplecursoradapter

I'm developing an Android application (unfortunately) for my coursework. I need to use a SimpleCursorAdapter to display a custom ListView of appointments. The constructor of the SimpleCursorAdapter takes a cursor as a parameter and this cursor needs to select all the columns that need to be displayed in the listView.

My problem is that everytime I run the application, it complains that: 'column '_id' does not exist' but there is a column called id! Where am I going wrong?

Below is the relevant code:

```
public class AppointmentsDB {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "appointment_db";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "appointment_table";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String KEY_PRIORITY = "priority";
    public static final String KEY_DATE_TIME = "date_time";
    public static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    public static final String KEY_ALARM_TIME = "alarm_time";

    private DatabaseHelper appointmentsDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase appointmentsDB;
    private final Context context;

    public AppointmentsDB(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        appointmentsDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openReadableDatabase()
    {
        return appointmentsDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openWritableDatabase()
    {
        return appointmentsDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public long addAppointment(Appointment appointment)
    {
        //
    }

    public void close()
    {
        //
    }

    static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        Context context;

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

            this.context = context;

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
            query.append("CREATE TABLE "+DATABASE_TABLE+" ");
            query.append("(");
            query.append(KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ");
            query.append(KEY_TITLE+" TEXT NOT NULL, ");
            query.append(KEY_DESCRIPTION+" TEXT, ");
            query.append(KEY_PRIORITY+" INTEGER, ");
            query.append(KEY_DATE_TIME+" INTEGER, ");
            query.append(KEY_DURATION+" INTEGER, ");
            query.append(KEY_ALARM_TIME+" INTEGER");
            query.append(");");

            ContentValues test = new ContentValues();

            db.execSQL(query.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

```
private Cursor cursor;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AppointmentsDB dbHelper = new AppointmentsDB(this);

    // Execute query that selects all appointments.
    // Store cursor from that query in local variable 'cursor'.
    // Pass 'cursor' to SimpleCursorAdapter.
    // SimpleCursorAdapter uses 'cursor' to display all appointments in
    // listview.

    StringBuilder selectQuery = new StringBuilder();
    selectQuery.append("SELECT "+AppointmentsDB.KEY_ID+" ,");
    selectQuery.append(AppointmentsDB.KEY_TITLE + ", ");
    selectQuery.append(AppointmentsDB.KEY_DESCRIPTION + ", ");
    selectQuery.append(AppointmentsDB.KEY_PRIORITY + ", ");
    selectQuery.append(AppointmentsDB.KEY_DATE_TIME + ", ");
    selectQuery.append(AppointmentsDB.KEY_DURATION + ", ");
    selectQuery.append(AppointmentsDB.KEY_ALARM_TIME + " FROM "
            + AppointmentsDB.DATABASE_TABLE /*+ " "*/);
    selectQuery.append("ORDER BY " + AppointmentsDB.KEY_DATE_TIME
            + " ASC");

    cursor = dbHelper.openReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
            selectQuery.toString(), null);

    String[] columnNames = new String[]{""};
    int[] ids = new int[]{};

    AppointmentsCursorAdapter adapter = new AppointmentsCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.row,cursor,columnNames,ids);
    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

// This class sets our customised layout for the ListView

class AppointmentsCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter
{

    private Context context;
    private int layout;
    private int[] colours;

    public AppointmentsCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) 
    {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);

        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        //...
    }


    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

        TextView titleText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        TextView priorityView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.priorityView);
        TextView dateText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateText);
        TextView monthText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.monthText);
        TextView timeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timeText);

        //...

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);


        TextView titleText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        TextView priorityView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.priorityView);
        TextView dateText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateText);
        TextView monthText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.monthText);
        TextView timeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timeText);

        //...

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is the column supposed to be called `_id` or `id`?

Comment: Dont know about java, but I can see you have an _ (underscore) in your code (_id), but only one (1) underscore in your code: AppointmentsDB.KEY_ID. Shoundt it be AppointmentsDB.KEY__ID (two underscores if the column id is named "_id") ?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: according to some other StackOverflow answers, there must be a column named _id. My table includes it but it still says column _id does not exist.

Comment: @LalitPoptani: I have included the _id column in my query!

Comment: If you added the `_id` column at a later time(and didn't increase the databse version) try to uninstall the app and then run it again so the database will be recreated with the new changes(or increase the database version in the `SQLiteOpenHelper`).

Comment: You didn't check for errors at the time of table creation. You would be well served to do that (even if there aren't any in this version of code). I would suggest for now though, you use the sqlite3 tool that is built into your emulator (or extract your database and use the same tool on *nix / Windows) and examine your actual schema (using the .schema command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String[] columnNames = new String[]{AppointmentsDB.KEY_ID};
int[] ids = new int[]{R.id.the_id_of_the_edittext_textview_or_wahtever_you_use_in_row_layout};
```

Also, unlesss you want to do fancy things, maybe you can simply use a SimpleCursorAdapter like this:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, columnNames, ids, CursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

I would also recommend using a ListFragment instead of ListActivity so you can reuse the list in other activities or situations (tablets...) if needed.

Comment: Now it says column '' does not exist :/

Comment: I do want to do fancy things! I've made a custom ListView row and I want to merge the data from the database with the row.

Comment: What about: `String[] columnNames = new String[]{AppointmentsDB.KEY_ID, AppointmentsDB.KEY_TITLE, AppointmentsDB.KEY_DESCRIPTION, AppointmentsDB.KEY_PRIORITY, AppointmentsDB.KEY_DATE_TIME, AppointmentsDB.KEY_DURATION, AppointmentsDB.KEY_ALARM_TIME};` ??  (forget about int[] ids you assign layout ids inside your custom adapter, so leave it as you had it)

Comment: I followed your first suggestion, and changed the Database version number and it works fine now. Thank you so much! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

rename the column to id and change the select statement to: "SELECT "+AppointmentsDB.KEY_ID+" AS _id ,"